# Cordova File Transfer download `result` null error

Tags: cordova, file-transfer, cordova-plugins

I have recently updated the cordova file-transfer plugin and have fixed the `.toURL()` paths as far as i can see although I am getting an error in the `FileTransfer.js` where the result from the download is `null` and it's not expecting it.

```
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'result.lengthComputable')
```

The error happens on this line:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/www/FileTransfer.js#L171

The file being downloaded is:
http://api.gigstamp.com/1/gigstamps/53179dcbc2cba20200000005-small.png

Here's an image showing the break:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qd80zgpy5r6btc/Screenshot%202014-04-26%2022.48.14.png

Comment: Are you trying over the iOS Simulator or real device?

Comment: I have tried it on both and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you find this out? I'm getting this exact error now...

Comment: I had to add a line `if (result) {` in to the FileTransfer.js as a temporary work around

Answer (score 1):

I've investigated same problem recently and I've found out that fileTransfer.download callback is calling with download progress and last call has result = null. Digging in Objective C sources came with information that fileTransfer can't get file entry. 
Don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: hey, I'm at least glad it's not just me. have you worked out a way around it?

Comment: yeah, I've returned to file-transfer@0.4.2 :/

Answer (score 1):

got same problem after upgrading to cordova 3.5.0 : TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'result.lengthComputable')

I think it's a url problem :

Digging into CDVFileTransfer::connectionDidFinishLoading I found that this line

[self.filePlugin makeEntryForURL:self.targetURL]

always return null with a non cdv filename style so I changed my whole target url from

file://image.png

to

cdvfile://localhost/persistent/image.png

and everything works now.